# package repository

Tags: miktex, repositories

I tried to download the basic installation package but I received the following errors:
[image: The connection has timed out]
[image: The site can't be reached]
I know how to download updates from other repository through the console but to download the basic installation package from the browser, I don't seem to have any clue how to choose another repository, can you help!

Can I set the browser to download all miktex related files from another repository instead of this default one!

Mirror: ftp.yzu.edu.tw (Taiwan) =>This site has never worked for me!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! To download the basic install, simply go to [MiKTeX home page](https://miktex.org/download).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories and manipulate the link provided by the Download-Button (e.g. https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/basic-miktex-2.9.6643-x64.exe).

Answer (score 1):

`MiKTeX Update` lets you choose the package repository within a world-wide list:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is not about getting an aupdate, but about downloading the Basic Installer. The problem with the Basic installer is, that the MiKTeX website does an automated load deistribution to the servers, obviously.

Comment: I feel like there are both questions in one. For downloading the basic installer, any CTAN mirror will make it available, anyway.